# Adding nested dictionary to another one

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, contacts

would like to make a contact book using dictinaries but i cant figure out how to add a nested dict to the current dict i have.

would be something like this

```
my_contacts = {"1": { "Tom Jones", "911",  "22.10.1995"},
           "2": { "Bob Marley",  "0800838383",  "22.10.1991"}
           }


def add_contact():
    user_input = int(input("please enter how many contacts you wanna add: "))
    for i in range(user_input):
        name = input("Enter the name: ")
        number = input("Enter the number: ")
        birthday = input("Enter the birthday")
        adress = input("Enter the address")

        my_contacts[name] = number
        my_contacts[birthday] = adress
```

but unforunatly this doesnt add them as a dict. so how can i add them as one dict inside my current dict?

```
my_contacts = {"1": { "Tom Jones", "911",  "22.10.1995"},
           "2": { "Bob Marley",  "0800838383",  "22.10.1991"}
           }


def add_contact():
    user_input = int(input("please enter how many contacts you wanna add: "))
    for i in range(user_input):
        name = input("Enter the name: ")
        number = input("Enter the number: ")
        birthday = input("Enter the birthday")
        adress = input("Enter the address")

        my_contacts[name] = number
        my_contacts[birthday] = adress
```

Comment: Within the loop, create a temporary `dict` first, _then_ you add that temporary dict into the 'master' dict (`my_contacts`).

Comment: Your nested dics don't have any keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a nice solution for you.

All i'm doing here is every time you iterate inside your for loop you are creating a new dictionary of the details you want to put in for a contact and adding that dictionary to the original dictionary, therefor adding a new contact as a dictionary. There should be some extra error handling of course but this for now may be a good solution.

```
my_contacts = {1: {"Name": "Tom Jones",
                   "Number": "911",
                   "Birthday": "22.10.1995",
                   "Address": "212 street"},
               2: {"Name": "Bob Marley",
                   "Number": "0800838383",
                   "Birthday": "22.10.1991",
                   "Address": "31 street"}
           }


def add_contact():
    user_input = int(input("please enter how many contacts you wanna add: "))
    index = len(my_contacts) + 1
    for _ in range(user_input):
        details = {}
        name = input("Enter the name: ")
        number = input("Enter the number: ")
        birthday = input("Enter the birthday")
        address = input("Enter the address")

        details["Name"] = name
        details["Number"] = number
        details["Birthday"] = birthday
        details["Address"] = address

        my_contacts[index] = details
        index += 1
```

Comment: cant find a better solution man thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you have here:

```
my_contacts = {"1": { "Tom Jones", "911",  "22.10.1995"},
           "2": { "Bob Marley",  "0800838383",  "22.10.1991"}
           }
```

Is a dict of sets (mapping a string to a set), not a dict of dicts.

1.Pass the current contacts to your function (so you can add new contact, not create them from scratch)

2.Create a new dict for the new contact

3.Add it to the passed contacts dict

```
def add_contact(contacts: dict)->None:
    user_input = int(input("please enter how many contacts you wanna add: "))
    for i in range(user_input):
        name = input("Enter the name: ")
        number = input("Enter the number: ")
        birthday = input("Enter the birthday")
        address = input("Enter the address")
        new_contact = {"name":name, "number":number, "birthday":birthday, "address":address}
        next_key = str(max([int(k) for k in contacts.keys()])+1)
        contacts[new_key] = new_contact
```